# brushless for outboard of a 4 meter boat

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

SK3 - 6364-190kv Brushless Outrunner Motor ... this motor has a nominal voltage of 37 V with a maximum current of 65 A, Can I supply this motor with a voltage of 24 V, with a current of 30 A? how much couple do I lose?

---

thank you all for the clarifications. In your opinion, to move a 4-meter boat at a speed of 5 nodi, is a torque greater than 10nm needed?

Answer (score 1):

Torque (couple?) is proportional to current. With only 30 amps available, the motor should not be loaded with more than about 45% of rated torque. Limiting the voltage to 24 V (65% of rated) will probably limit the speed to 65% of rated speed. Limiting the speed will probably reduce the torque in proportion to the square of speed 0.65 squared is 0.42 or 42%. That should be enough for the motor to handle with the power supply limit. That is just a guess based on the limited details given. If you can find data on the motor, controller and propellor, a better estimate could be made.

Answer (score 0):

**[Specs.](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-aerodrive-sk3-6364-190kv-brushless-outrunner-motor.html?___store=en_us)**
Turns: 18T
Voltage: 10S Lipoly    (37 Vmax)
RPM/V: 190KV
Internal resistance: 0.028 Ohm
Max Loading: 65A   ( surge = 37V/0.028Ω = **1321A**  start , ideal voltage source)
Max Power: 2450W = ? 37*65A=2405W hmm
Shaft Dia: 8.0mm
Bolt holes: 32mm
Bolt thread: M4
Weight: 697g
Motor Plug: 4mm Bullet Connector

What this means is if your battery is limited to 30A peak current then start torque will be 30/2405 = 2% of spec.

But if it is average current then with 24V it is 720W/2405= 30% of rated power and only 24V/37V=65% or rated RPM.

p.s. I hope it has water cooling.  However @ 30A it will run cooler with Pd=30^2*0.028Ω=25 Watts

Answer (score 0):

With 24V you can still supply 65A with duty cycle below 35%. So for low speed no problem. For higher speed you will loose just above 50% of torque - it is proportional to current.

Because of the voltage your speed will also be limited.